# NE555 output voltage is too low

Tags: oscilloscope, 555, astable

I'm trying to make a simple astable circuit. It should be one of the easiest ones in history of electronics, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my design:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8G9Xk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output voltage remains too low. About 1.5 V peak to peak.

(For my application this is less important, but maybe it could be useful to note also that the calculated frequency differs from the real one of about 30 KHz.)

I tried a different power supply and also a different ne555 IC.
Could someone please explain to me why the voltage is so low?

[image]

Comment: Were you measuring the output on an oscilloscope?

Comment: Where were you measuring? Output (pin 3) to ground? across C1? The basic circuit is fine and yes you do get a deviation from 'calculated' frequency due to tolerances in component values. You should also check the actual values used just in case - its easy to pick up the wrong resistor (red and orange bands can look very similar) or capacitor.

Comment: Spehro Pefhany probably has the correct answer, but you should also just try swapping the 555 if it isn't soldered in.

Comment: I measured with an oscilloscope, pin 3 to ground. I already swapped the 555 several times... I'll try with Spehro solution..

Comment: <Cough> That's about 0.8V.  Are you sure you're not using a 10:1 probe and have neglected to inform the oscilloscope? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your problem might be that you are using a X10 scope probe but the scope thinks that you have a X1 probe attached.

The output of a NE555 doesn't go all the way to Vcc - there is an internal voltage drop of more than 1 Volt.

If you look closely at your scope waveform, I see an amplitude of about either 0.8V (X1 probe) or 8V (X10 probe).  I'm putting my money on X10 probe.

It is also possible that the probe compensation isn't adjusted properly.

In other words, I think that you are dealing with a measurement problem rather than a circuit problem.

Answer (score 3):

The calculated frequency (datasheet equation) for that configuration is about 195kHz.

The calculations are invalid, however, since the bipolar version of the 555 (NE555) only barely works to 100kHz.

You can try the CMOS version (eg. [TLC555](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc555.pdf)) which will work fine at that frequency. You might want to consider increasing the resistor values somewhat (maybe 3-5:1) and decreasing the timing capacitor.

You can verify this with the circuit you have simply by increasing the timing capacitor (say to 10nF).

Comment: Typo in 3rd paragraph. You meant _increasing_ the timing capacitor, I think.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I did mean to decrease the capacitance- so the  product is the same, in order to get the same frequency. Eg. 3K/10K/330pF

Comment: thank you Spehro for the suggestion, I'll try that tonight and I'll let you know! I honestly didn't know about this frequency limitation...

Comment: it doesn't work... I tried 10 different frequencies, from 1 KHz to 50 KHz, but the amplitude is still the same. I attached the scope screenshot to the first post.. what's wrong? that's really annoying..

Comment: I don't see any screen shot at this time. Have you verified the 9V supply on the oscilloscope? Your number is off by about 5:1 which is a bit suspicious.

Comment: it was uploading the image, now it's there. I verified the 9V supply with a multimeter, and it's ok.. But the problem remains even if I use different power supplies

Comment: See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit is fine. The problem is that the frequency is too fast and there are more LOW than HIGH outputs, so the 555 has not totally turned on for 1/3 of the time, so it doesn't give you rail voltage output. Here is what I suggest you to do. First, change c1 to higher value. Second change R2 to 1k, same as R1, this will give you 1/2 on, and 1/2 off output timing which will increase your output voltage.

Comment: Bad answer: R1 = R2 does NOT give a 50% duty cycle.

Comment: This makes no sense. Its the comparator inputs (trigger, threshold) that are set for 1/3 and 2/3rd supply voltage. Until the capacitor charges or discharges to these levels the output doesn't change. Secondly (R1+R2)*C determines the charging part of the cycle (High output) and R2*C determines the discharge (low output). Making these resistors equal does not give a 1:1 mark/space ratio. Thirdly - with these values shown the oscillator is about 200kHz

Comment: Frequency has nothing to do with voltage or power.  This answer has a number of wrong conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, shame on me..
As Spehro and Dwayne pointed out, I accidentaly move the probe switch to 10X instead of 1X, and the scope was set to 1X.

That's really embarassing :) 
thanks everybody!